# Z-index on Polymer hero transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, polymer

I am trying to make a slideshow transition to full screen as shown here: http://alexfuhr.me/polymer-talk/ (the trigger for this is clicking the button at the top right)

The transition to a full screen works fine, but the transition back to the inline view causes the fullscreen slideshow to suddenly fall underneath the scaffolding. I have tried to change z-index to high numbers to rectify this, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix this transition? The main code is here: https://github.com/afuhrtrumpet/afuhrtrumpet.github.io/blob/master/polymer-talk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mucking around with `z-index` to overlay elements on top of each other, the following approach might offer a better solution.

The idea is to *hide* the **drawer** of the `core-drawer-panel` (inside the `core-scaffold`) by setting the `narrow` attribute to `true` before the forward animation starts, and then restore the value before the back animation starts.

Also, this issue only happens when the **drawer** is visible on the screen. So we only need to subscribe to the `core-animated-pages-transition-prepare` event when the page is *not* in narrow mode.

Something like the following should work. Personally I prefer this 'cause it also animates the in/out of the drawer panel smoothly, indicating that the `fullscreen-list` takes up the full screen space.

```
<script>
    var isBackAnimation = false;
    var pages = document.querySelector("#mainPages");
    var fab = document.querySelector("#fullscreen-button");

    var switchPages = function () {
        isBackAnimation = pages.selected == 0;
        pages.selected = pages.selected == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        fab.icon = pages.selected == 1 ? "unfold-less" : "unfold-more";
    }

    window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function () {
        // locate the core-drawer-panel inside the core-scaffold
        var drawerPanel = document.querySelector('core-scaffold::shadow #drawerPanel');

        // on loaded, listen to this event only when it's not in narrow mode
        if (!drawerPanel.narrow) {
            pages.addEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-prepare', beforeAnimation);
        }

        drawerPanel.addEventListener('core-responsive-change', function (event) {
            // in narrow mode, the animations work fine, so we remove the handlers
            if (event.detail.narrow) {
                pages.removeEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-prepare', beforeAnimation);
            }
            // otherwise we add the handlers
            else {
                pages.addEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-prepare', beforeAnimation);

                // when the page was initially in narrow mode and then got resized up, we 
                // need to manually reset the narrow attribute at the end of the animation
                if (isBackAnimation) {
                    pages.addEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-end', afterAnimation);
                }
            }
        });

        function beforeAnimation() {
            drawerPanel.narrow = !drawerPanel.narrow;
        }

        function afterAnimation() {
            drawerPanel.narrow = !drawerPanel.narrow;

            // this is a once off thing, so unsubscribe it here
            pages.removeEventListener('core-animated-pages-transition-end', afterAnimation);
        }
    });
</script>
```